# For Loop conversion to apply/plyr

Tags: r, for-loop, apply, plyr

I've written the following code and would like to improve it by using plyr or apply, alas I cannot seem to get it to work. The idea is to identify the correct column and then extract/fetch the appropriate value.

```
df <- data.frame(ID=c(1,2,3,4,5),COUNTRY=c('NL','FR','NL','BE','NL'),
             NL_GEN=c(5,5,10,20,5),FR_GEN=c(15,10,10,25,5),BE_GEN=c(10,10,5,15,5))

col_sel <- vector('numeric',length=nrow(df))
for ( i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  col_sel[i] <- as.numeric(df[i,grep(paste(df$COUNTRY[i],"_GEN",sep = ""),names(df))])
}
```

How can I use plyr or apply to pass through 1 line at a time and return a single value instead of the whole column?

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider `vapply()` with `seq_along()` that allows you to specify the output, here being a numeric vector:

```
new_col_sel <- vapply(seq_along(df), function(i) {
      df[i, grep(paste0(df$COUNTRY[i], "_GEN"), names(df))]
}, numeric(1))

new_col_sel   
# [1]  5 10 10 15  5

all.equal(col_sel, new_col_sel)
# [1] TRUE
```

If needing to add a column to dataframe, simply assign it:

```
df$col_sel <- vapply(seq_along(df), function(i) {
     df[i, grep(paste0(df$COUNTRY[i], "_GEN"), names(df))]
}, numeric(1))

#   ID COUNTRY NL_GEN FR_GEN BE_GEN col_sel
# 1  1      NL      5     15     10       5
# 2  2      FR      5     10     10      10
# 3  3      NL     10     10      5      10
# 4  4      BE     20     25     15      15
# 5  5      NL      5      5      5       5
```

Comment: Thank you, the code didn't work exactly on my complete dataset, giving an error of "Error in vapply .......values must be type 'double' ..." due to the fact that the numbers are stored as text, but easy fix.

Answer (score 0):

I think we can use `adply` from the `plyr` package:

```
library(plyr)
adply(df, 1, function(x) c(Result = x[,which(grepl(x$COUNTRY, names(x)))]))

#   ID COUNTRY NL_GEN FR_GEN BE_GEN Result
# 1  1      NL      5     15     10      5
# 2  2      FR      5     10     10     10
# 3  3      NL     10     10      5     10
# 4  4      BE     20     25     15     15
# 5  5      NL      5      5      5      5
```

Comment: Hi, I'm getting the following error "Error in list_to_dataframe(res, attr(.data, "split_labels"), .id, id_as_factor) : Results must be all atomic, or all data frames". I assume it must have to do with COUNTRY being char as I have corrected them the others to all numeric.... still not working :/

Comment: @Voltorr that sounds like an issue with your data, do you have more columns than `*_GEN` that contain the country names?